# Add two json values dynamically in azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to add two json value which is coming dynamically from one activity and one variable value  of pipeline in data factory.

I am doing it like this as below.
@union(activity('Get Order Events Data').output, json('{"orig_orderID" : "variables('orderid')"}'))

But it is showing error.
Missing comma between arguments

What i am doing wrong here.

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot of your `Get Order Events Data` activity's output?

Comment: I am unable to attach it.Here are sample output data.
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 145,
            "order_id": 256,
            "created_at": "2021-06-20T11:48:20Z",
            "type": 10,
            "sender": -1,
            "message": null,
            "previous_status": 4,
            "fas_user_id": null,
            "event_data": "5",
            "shopkeeper_timestamp": null,
            "store_id": 123,

Comment: So you want to get this output?`{"data":[ { "id": 145, "order_id": 256, "created_at": "2021-06-20T11:48:20Z", "type": 10, "sender": -1, "message": null, "previous_status": 4, "fas_user_id": null, "event_data": "5", "shopkeeper_timestamp": null, "store_id": 123,"orig_orderID":your variable's value}]}`

Comment: Yes i want to add this variable value  in data of other activity. value of orig_orderID" = "860"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it is showing error. Missing comma between arguments

This is the expression `variables('orderid')` has `'` in it which splits your expression.

You should use `concat()` function to do this `@union(activity('Get Order Events Data').output, json(concat('{"orig_orderID" :',variables('orderid'),'}')))`. But this
expression can't get your expected result due to it wouldn't add in your data. It would be like this:

```
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 145,
                "order_id": 256,
                "created_at": "2021-06-20T11:48:20Z",
                "type": 10,
                "sender": -1,
                "message": null,
                "previous_status": 4,
                "fas_user_id": null,
                "event_data": "5",
                "shopkeeper_timestamp": null,
                "store_id": 123
            }
        ],
        "orig_orderID": "860"
    }
```

You can try the following expression:`@union(activity('Get Order Events Data').output.data[0], json(concat('{"orig_orderID" :',variables('orderid'),'}')))`

it can get the result:

```
    {
        "id": 145,
        "order_id": 256,
        "created_at": "2021-06-20T11:48:20Z",
        "type": 10,
        "sender": -1,
        "message": null,
        "previous_status": 4,
        "fas_user_id": null,
        "event_data": "5",
        "shopkeeper_timestamp": null,
        "store_id": 123,
        "orig_orderID": "860"
    }
```

Comment: Hi steve..I need to write whole expression in body of api in web activity.
When i implemented this expression i got this warning.
Expression of type: 'Array[Any]' does not match the field: 'body'

Comment: @shashankshekhar Ignore this warning. It can work on my side.